# How do i make the result of base64enc::base64decode human readable

Tags: r

I have some text that is base 64 encoded and want to decode it in R. The package im using is base64decode of the base64enc package. The problem I have is that its not human readable. How do i make it work

e.g. This is what i get from a text string that was endcoded from "exampleEncodedText"

```
 base64enc::base64decode("ZXhhbXBsZUVuY29kZWRUZXh0")
 [1] 65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 45 6e 63 6f 64 65 64 54 65 78 74
```

For reference i encoded it on https://www.base64decode.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?base64decode` says that this function decodes a base64-encoded string into binary data. So, using `rawToChar` gives a human readable character:

```
rawToChar(base64decode("ZXhhbXBsZUVuY29kZWRUZXh0"))
[1] "exampleEncodedText"
```